# Intermittent issue - NullPointerException after period of inactivity, often after orientation change on iOS devices only

Tags: codenameone

I have been receiving NullPointerException reports  as per below. Often they occur just after the device orientation changes. example report below: -

```
[EDT] 11:19:53,486 - Orientation changed to Landscape - showHomeForm 
[EDT] 11:19:53,490 - line 572 
[EDT] 11:19:53,495 - line 574 
[EDT] 11:19:53,935 - line 576 
[EDT] 11:19:53,940 - Orientation changed to Landscape Finished - showHomeForm 
[EDT] 11:19:53,954 - line 565 
[EDT] 11:19:53,957 - Orientation changed to Portrait Finished - showHomeForm 
[EDT] 11:19:58,803 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.getDisplaySafeArea:256 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.snapToSafeAreaInternal:2395 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.calcPreferredSize:3176 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.preferredSizeImpl:3545 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.preferredSize:3584 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.getPreferredSize:1449 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.getPreferredH:1539 
at com_codename1_ui_layouts_BorderLayout.positionTopBottom:477 
at com_codename1_ui_layouts_BorderLayout.layoutContainer:317 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2583 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.layoutContainer:2219 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2588 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.layoutContainer:2219 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2588 
at com_codename1_ui_Form.sizeChangedInternal:881 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2514 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1300 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1218 
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120 
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176 
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153 

[EDT] 11:19:58,823 - Exception in My App version 2.03 
[EDT] 11:19:58,827 - OS ios 
[EDT] 11:19:58,832 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException 
[EDT] 11:19:58,836 - Current Form VXSMS_Main 
[EDT] 11:19:58,840 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.getDisplaySafeArea:256 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.snapToSafeAreaInternal:2395 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.calcPreferredSize:3176 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.preferredSizeImpl:3545 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.preferredSize:3584 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.getPreferredSize:1449 
at com_codename1_ui_Component.getPreferredH:1539 
at com_codename1_ui_layouts_BorderLayout.positionTopBottom:477 
at com_codename1_ui_layouts_BorderLayout.layoutContainer:317 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2583 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.layoutContainer:2219 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2588 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.layoutContainer:2219 
at com_codename1_ui_Container.doLayout:2588 
at com_codename1_ui_Form.sizeChangedInternal:881 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2514 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1300 
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1218 
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120 
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176 
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

The method where the null pointer occures is below: -

```
@Override
    public Rectangle getDisplaySafeArea(Rectangle rect) {
        if (rect == null) {
            rect = new Rectangle();
        }
        int x = nativeInstance.getDisplaySafeInsetLeft();
        int y = nativeInstance.getDisplaySafeInsetTop();
        int w = getDisplayWidth() - nativeInstance.getDisplaySafeInsetRight() - x;
        int h = getDisplayHeight() - nativeInstance.getDisplaySafeInsetBottom() - y;
        rect.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        
        return rect;
    }
```

where line 256 is here: -

```
int x = nativeInstance.getDisplaySafeInsetLeft();
```

This would suggest that nativeInstance is null somehow? However it is initialized: -

```
public static IOSNative nativeInstance = new IOSNative();
```

Below is code I use within a orientation listener: -

```
    VXSMS_Main.addOrientationListener((ActionListener) new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            if(Display.getInstance().isPortrait()){
                Log.p("Orientation changed to Portrait - showHomeForm");                    
                l_Home.setHidden(false);
                Log.p("line 571");
                HomeButtoncont.setScrollableY(false);
                Log.p("line 573");
                HomeButtoncont.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(400);
                Log.p("line 575");
                Log.p("Orientation changed to Portrait Finished - showHomeForm");
            }
            else{
                Log.p("Orientation changed to Landscape - showHomeForm");
                l_Home.setHidden(true);
                Log.p("line 582");
                HomeButtoncont.setScrollableY(true);
                Log.p("line 584");
                HomeButtoncont.getParent().animateLayoutAndWait(400);
                Log.p("line 586");
                Log.p("Orientation changed to Landscape Finished - showHomeForm");
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong or bad practice in the code I am using to manage the orientation. Can I safeguard against this somehow?

Further information; HomeButtoncont is a container with 4 MultiButtons. This only occurs with iOS and I have only been able to recreate this issue myself once. It was after a long period of inactivity. After this time, opening the app, the iPhone was displaying a message of low battery. I then rotated the device a few times.

Comment: The native instance isn't null. The stack ends at the boundary of the native code where we don't have the stack frame. That means there was a fault within the native code somewhere. I'm guessing the [safe area insets can be null](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/IOSNative.m#L8289). Assuming this is the case it should be an easy fix. I'll just verify this with Steve.

Comment: Thanks for the info Shai. Do you need me to raise an issue or will you be able update me here?

Comment: I suggest filing an issue just so we can keep track of it for sure and make sure it doesn't slip between the cracks.

Comment: Ok issue filed https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3764